# TypeScript React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm fetching data from Nasa API. This is my PagesData type on types.ts and state definition :

```
export type PagesData = {
 copyright?: String;
 date: String;
 explanation: String;
 url: String;
 media_type: String;
 title: String;
};
```

and my state definition :

```
const initialValues = {
 copyright: '',
 date: '',
 explanation: '',
 url: '',
 media_type: '',
 title: '',
};
const [data, setData] = useState<PagesData>(initialValues);

...
fetch block
...
const newData: PagesData = await res.json();
setData(newData);
```

My issue is i get an extra property field on data, but i dont need.

[image: console.log]

Comment: If you don't need it - don't use )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript does not automatically filter out data for you. If you get a JSON file with lots of redundant information, you could manually filter it out. In this example I only use `url` and `title` from the `rawJsonData` object.

```
type PagesData = {
  url:string,
  title:string
}


let rawJsonData:any = {
  title:"just a test",
  url:"www.test.com",
  id:4
}

const {title, url} = rawJsonData
let dataWithoutExtras:PagesData = {title, url}
```